# Updating deployment

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, heroku, deployment

I recently deployed a nodejs API through Heroku. I want to update the new changes to the deployment but whenever I push (git push Heroku master) I receive an error.

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/app/seeds'

This started behaving this way after I ran `npm install pg`

Comment: you should be using `git push origin master`

Comment: if you are not sure what is your origin then check using `git remote -v`

Comment: The origins are just links... and when I do git push origin it doesn't update the API

Comment: doing `git push origin` or `git push origin master` ?

Comment: I did git push origin master

Answer (score 1):

While deploying the changes to Heroku it is unable to find /app/seeds directory and so it will not be able to be pushed to Heroku and this is what causes a problem.

Maybe some of your files do have got deleted. So here what you can do is delete your node_modules folder and just run the command `npm install` so all your packages should be having completed files and then do git push heroku master.

I also faced a similar issue and it resolved my problem. So can you please give it a try.

Comment: So i deleted the node_modules then installed them back and then when I did the push it gave me the same error

Comment: Do you remember the exact process or any additional details.

Comment: my situation was similar but it got resolved. But here there is some problem with the dependencies itself as while deploying to git, Heroku/git is unable to find the required directory. 

Also, Heroku doesn't allow to push empty directories so check the directory where the error is reporting and create one empty file there and then try to push.

If the above solution doesn't work then please go through this article mentioned below:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git